# Refresh page after Message box in ASP.NET using C# RSS

Tags: c#

Hey guys On submit button i am using the below script to display messagebox in the webpage :

```
ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "Alert", "alert('Wrong verification code');", true);
```

I want to refresh the page after pressing ok button in this messagebox i.e. all controls should go blank.

Please do help me in this.

Answer (score 1):

Use window.location.reload()

Try this:

```
ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript
(
    this.GetType(), 
    "Alert", 
    "alert('Wrong verification code'); window.location.reload();",
    true
);
```

Comment: Even using window.location.reload() it does not refresh the page.

Comment: it does not give me any error but it does not refresh the page even after clicking OK button on alert box.

Answer (score 0):

Call server side event after alert message like:

```
document.getElementById('ctl00_MainContentContainer_ticket1_YesBtn').click();
```

It will take you on code behind page.